# Keeping alive Thin servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon, redmine, thin

I have a Redmine installation running with 3 instances within Thin. The first 3 clicks are slow as hell, I guess because Thin is launching the instances for the first time then. But it doesn't seem to keep them alive, as, when coming back after a minute or so, it takes way too long again.

I couldn't find any config options regarding this except for the timeout setting. But I think this timeout setting is meant for connection timeouts and not instances per se.

Does anyone know how to keep the instances alive, maybe even pre-start them? Is it possible by using just config options within my site.yml?

Here's my config, pretty much a default one:

```
--- 
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
address: 0.0.0.0
timeout: 30
port: 3000
log: log/thin.log
max_conns: 1024
require: []
max_persistent_conns: 512
environment: production
servers: 3
daemonize: true
chdir: /var/www/clients/client1/web26/_tools/redmine
```

Thanks for your help!

edit: Seems like I'm wrong with my theory. Thin servers are staying alive. But the problem persists. The first (n instances) clicks in a row are slow like if it's starting the app.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be something to do with apache and mod_proxy.  If using Apache see this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#ProxyPass and make sure you set min to at least 1.  That way one thread will always be running, otherwise I believe it will kill the thread after so much time resulting in a slow loading time until the thread is restablished.